# is this custom logging threadsafe?

Tags: c#

I have a custom logging routine and want to check if it will be threadsafe as I will call it from several events. the entry point will be logevents(message)

```
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
public class mystuff {

 private static object writeLock = new object();
 private static string eventsLogfile = "";
 private void logEvent(object message) {
  // To enqueue the write
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(WriteToFile, DateTime.Now + " " + Instrument.FullName + " " + message.ToString());

 }
 private void WriteToFile(object msg) {

  lock(writeLock) {

   using(var writer = File.AppendText(eventsLogfile)) {
    writer.WriteLine((string) msg);
   }
  }


 }
```

Comment: Yes, it should be because you have a static lock. Which means when one thread comes in to use it, the lock will be set - this will prevent other threads trying to access the code. You may want to `try...catch` around the `using` to make sure that you release the lock (but this may not be entirely necessary)

Comment: Here is the [msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/c5kehkcz.aspx)

Comment: Depending on how you run/deploy this, your timestamps will be all over the place.  They're at minimum subject to the system time zone and culture, and the currently running program can mess with that too (nothing like switching between European and US date formats for confusion there...).  Log stamps should almost universally be stored as UTC (or at least marked with the current offset), and you should apply a static, SARGable format too (usually ISO).  Otherwise, you can have only one log, which might be limiting.